# OpenCart 3.0.2 Meta Desciption is limited up to 100 characters

Tags: opencart, meta

I am using opencart 3.0.2.0 version and its meta-description tag in the website is showing only up to 100 characters. I am able to save more than 100, but does not show them in the website.

I tried to increase it via the admin panel --> Extensions --> Extensions --> Themes --> Edit Theme --> List Description Limit. After that, flushed all of the caches but nothing happens.

Also, I tried to search in the files for such limitation but I was not able to find it. Most probably, I am missing something obvious.

Do you have suggestions on how to increase it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: John, are you talking about the Meta Tag Description on the product / category page?

Comment: Daniel, I am talking about the product meta description. Sorry for not specifying it.

Comment: No problem, can you clarify one other thing: are you (1) having trouble saving a meta description that's over 100 characters? (2) Unable to see more than 100 characters in the admin area text editor? (3) Unable to see more than 100 characters in the meta description of the product page on the front end?

Comment: I am able to save more than 100 characters in the meta description field in the product edit page. After I save the page it is showing the correct content in the admin panel when I open the page again. The issue is that on the product page(for the visitors) in the meta-description tag it is showing only up to 100 characters. It is the 3rd option you explained.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme or the standard Opencart theme?

Comment: I am using the theme NewStore v 2.5.6. I was not able to find any limitation in the theme's files.

Comment: That's strange, can you try switching to the default theme and checking if the issue persists?

Comment: Today I tried to change the theme but did not help. I will try to update the version of the OC just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart code and database default structure allows 255 characters of meta description. 
So if you are not able to find in code the other possible way to restrict length is altering column structure and limiting characters in table structure.
You can check table structure for product_description , category_description tables.

Comment: I have checked it and both tables are set to varchar(255) but it is showing only up to 100 charters.